# Formatting messages to send to socket.io node.js server from python client

Tags: python, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to get a Python client talking to a Node.js server using Socket.io 0.7, by sending a custom event to the server.

Based on the Socket.io reference I have found on [GitHub](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec), and the following [WebSocket Python library](https://github.com/liris/websocket-client).

Here's is my code so far:

**Node server**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('newimg', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
  });
});
```

**Python client**

```
def handshake(host, port):
    u = urlopen("http://%s:%d/socket.io/1/" % (host, port))
    if u.getcode() == 200:
        response = u.readline()
        (sid, hbtimeout, ctimeout, supported) = response.split(":")
        supportedlist = supported.split(",")
        if "websocket" in supportedlist:
            return (sid, hbtimeout, ctimeout)
        else:
            raise TransportException()
    else:
        raise InvalidResponseException()


try:
    (sid, hbtimeout, ctimeout) = handshake(HOSTNAME, PORT) #handshaking according to socket.io spec.
Except Exception as e:
    print e
    sys.exit(1)
ws = websocket.create_connection("ws://%s:%d/socket.io/1/websocket/%s" % (HOSTNAME, PORT, sid))
print ws.recv()
ws.send("2::")
ws.send("5:1::{'name':'newimg', 'args':'bla'}")
print ws.recv()
print "Closing connection"
ws.close()
```

**Node console output**

```
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized 12738935571241622933
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/12738935571241622933
debug - set heartbeat interval for client 12738935571241622933
debug - client authorized for 
debug - websocket writing 1::
debug - websocket received data packet 2::
debug - got heartbeat packet
debug - websocket received data packet 5:1::{'name':'newimg', 'args':'bla'}
debug - acknowledging packet automatically
debug - websocket writing 6:::1
info  - transport end
debug - set close timeout for client 12738935571241622933
debug - cleared close timeout for client 12738935571241622933
debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client 12738935571241622933
debug - discarding transport
```

**Python console output**

```
Done
1::
6:::1
Closing connection
```

Now it seems the socket event is not being triggered, despite the server responding with ACK. So the message is being correctly received but I am assuming, not formatted properly for socket.io to trigger an event.

I didn't think framing was necessary, however Archie1986 seems to disagree on his response to this: [Socket.IO Client Library in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762086/socket-io-client-library-in-python)

What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Resolved. Will accept my own answer as soon as I am allowed to do so. Problem was in using single, rather than double quotes for JSON.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Resolved. I needed to use double quotes. Single quotes are not valid JSON. Woops.

```
ws.send("5:1::{'name':'newimg', 'args':'bla'}")
```

Becomes:

```
ws.send('5:1::{"name":"newimg", "args":"bla"}')
```

Answer (score 21):

I wrapped [rod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/370115/rod)'s research into a [barebones socket.io client library](https://github.com/invisibleroads/socketIO-client).

```
pip install -U socketIO-client
python
    from socketIO_client import SocketIO
    with SocketIO('localhost', 8000) as socketIO:
        socketIO.emit('aaa')
        socketIO.wait(seconds=1)
```

Comment: What does socketIO.wait do?
is seconds=1 a timeout?