# What would be the python web framework to push real-time data to client from server eg Tornado?

Tags: python, mongodb, web-applications, flask, tornado

I'm having a problem in implementing an application using the Flask framework to send real-time data to a client browser. It will be streaming tweet user info to a client, using the twitter Streaming API(tweepy). Tweet information is also stored into a mongo DB, for future retrieval.

I assume this has to involve long-polling/ server side events(SSEs), which Flask doesn't seem to handle with ease. Juggernaut doesn't do it and is now deprecated in favour of SSEs.

Would Tornado be more suitable if I wanted to send real-time data to a client, or are there more appropriate web frameworks.

I am fairly new to python and it's the first time I'm trying to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Flask can handle long-polling or events, the main implementation problem is the WSGI server. Here's an example with gevent and websockets: https://gist.github.com/1185629

Comment: When I try the example in the link it gives me a 500 error.

Comment: Possible. The example i linked was just to illustrate how Flask can handle long polling. That GIST was made a year ago, it might not be compatible with your flask version. All that said, it's up to the WSGI server to support long polling / event, not flask.

Comment: Ok, would it be easier to use tornado which seems to support pushing data from server to client at the outset?

Comment: Another example of Flask, gevent, and gevent-websocket [https://bitbucket.org/jeunice/flask-ws-example](https://bitbucket.org/jeunice/flask-ws-example). Not a Web Sockets masterpiece, as it tries to remain parallel and comparable to my similar example of Flask and long-polling. But it gives the general idea, with a few refinements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use websocket witn [socket.io](http://socket.io/) and look ath [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762086/socket-io-client-library-in-python) about python client library.