# Python connect and send message to socket.io 1.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

Currently using the latest version of `socket.io`. I'm wondering how to connect to a namespaced socket via python (using the `websocket` module for instance).

My main goal is to send a message to the server. Just that. Is there anyone who knows how I can achieve this ?

I saw the `SocketIO-client` package on Pypi but it seems that it only works with Python 2.7 and I'm using 3.3.4.

I tried this what is said on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762086/socket-io-client-library-in-python) and adaptating it to my python version. Though that's what I get in my `hskey` object :

```py
>>> h = http.client.HTTPConnection('localhost:8008')
>>> h.request('POST', '/socket.io/1')
>>> resp = h.getresponse()
>>> hskey = resp.read()
>>> hskey
b'{"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}'
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? If so, please post it in an answer. I am having the same problem.

Comment: I think I never managed to solve the problem there. I just switched to something else I think (can't remember)