# How to use socket.io client in python?

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I used socket.io (javascript library) in my html file to send and get socket data, by this code:

```
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function () {
        socket.emit('msgSend', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
    })

    socket.on('msgReceive', function (msg) {
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    })
```

I use **node.js** server and **socket.io** in backend.

But now I want to use python as client.
How can I use python instead client javascript ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762086/socket-io-client-library-in-python , did you even try to Google? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client